# button onclick add input type="number" array via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function somar(){
document.getElementsByName("aQtd")[0].value++ ;
}
<tr><td>
<button type="button" name="cProduto" value="xyz" onclick="somar()">
<input  type="number" value="0" name="aQtd">
<tr><td>
<button type="button" name="cProduto" value="abc" onclick="somar()">
<input  type="number" value="0" name="aQtd">
<tr><td>
<button type="button" name="cProduto" value="zzz" onclick="somar()">
<input  type="number" value="0" name="aQtd">
```

I need while press button add +1 into respective array aQtd into  row
Note that same name aQtd and same name cProduto.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Do `input`s even have innerHTML? Also, can you set `innerHTML` to a number? I thought you could only set it to a string.

Comment: We probably want to be using `value` other than `innerHTML`. Also I'm assuming you want to increment each value. So : `document.getElementById("nQtd").value++` after you fix the multiple ID problem.

Comment: I remove ID, no relevant. How to sum into aQTD while click button ?
Button should work auto increment of array aQtd

Comment: where is the aQtd array?

Comment: HTML auto identifies aQTD like array because exist more than one.
In this example, aQtd = {1,2,3} elements with value = 0

Comment: I resolve the problem.
I add somar(0), somar(1), somar(2)
Modify line:
function somaqtd(x){
document.getElementsByName("aQtd")[x].value++ ;

Answer (score 1):

You had some problems with your html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="button" name="cProduto" value="xyz" onclick="somar(this)">BTN</button></td>
        <td><input  type="number" value="0" name="aQtd" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="button" name="cProduto" value="abc" onclick="somar(this)">BTN</button></td>
        <td><input  type="number" value="0" name="aQtd" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><button type="button" name="cProduto" value="zzz" onclick="somar(this)">BTN</button></td>
       <td><input  type="number" value="0" name="aQtd" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Plus, I assume that you wanted the button to influence it's own row's input:

```
function somar(elem){
    // you can do this better with jquery
    elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling.children[0].value++
}
```

And here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WkpBj/